# how to copy "speech to text" text in a string variable for string matching purpose?

Tags: c#

I'm a novice to C# i'm not sure if I'm writing on the right forum. I am building simple speech recognition program which takes voice command as input, performs speech to text translation and then searches a video matching to that text. 
I am currently storing output in text box but I want to store it in string.

I am unable to write correct logical code for storing recognized text into string, if anyone could advise me How can I do this ? here is my code...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    var ss    = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    var pb    = new PromptBuilder();
    var sre   = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    var clist = new Choices();

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
        btnStop.Enabled  = true;
        clist.Add(new string[] { "go away", "able", "active", "actual", "afraid", "busy", "casual" });
        Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(clist));

        try
        {
            sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            sre.LoadGrammar(gr);
            sre.SpeechRecognized+= sre_SpeechRecognized;
            sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
         }
    }

    private void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) =>
        textContent.Text += e.Result.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sre.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        btnStart.Enabled = true;
        btnStop.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where you are stuck - if you want to assign it to a string instead of the textbox, just replace `textContent.Text += e.Result.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;` with `string myString = e.Result.Text.ToString()` or if you want to store it for a longer time use an instance-variable like you already do with your clist etc.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but every time you click the start button you are adding the same words to your choice list over again. Unless you are doing other updates to the list, just set it in the constructor rather than in the start button method.  You're also performing similar repeated initializations to your `sre` object.